# Twitter bootstrap glyphicon appears on top

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this problem with the glyphicons from TB. In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/19/) you can see the `glyphicon glyphicon-search` appear on top of the `div` that slides under the purple square.

To see this effect, press the button on the right side.

My question is, how can I avoid that? By default, those glyphicons are `position:relative`, and I'd like to keep that.

Can't post this unless I show some code..

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
$('#slider').remove();

  var sliderDiv = "<div id='slider' " +
      "class='alert alert-info alert-dismissable' " +
      "style='position: absolute; width:240px;'> " +
      "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ornare condimentum sapien, vitae pulvinar libero ultrices sit amet.</div>";
    $(sliderDiv).insertAfter('#testing').hide().fadeIn('slow').wait(50000).slideUp('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `.alert-info` is positioned on click, just add:

```
.alert-info { 
    z-index: 10;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/20/)

Answer (score -2):

I have added a property to the `.glyphicon` class :

```
.glyphicon
 {
 z-index : -5;
}
```